Does knowledge of sexual activities make one Baligh?
السلام عليكم ورحمة الله وبركاته
Does having sexual knowledge and understanding of gender render an individual (whether male/female) to be considered Baligh whether an individual even if that child hasn't reached puberty?
This question came to my mind after listening to the short video below from a lecture on Nikah. This question comes while Daee Br Imran was discussing issues related to sex education in the link below!!!
Video for better understanding (unfortunately video is in Urdu. Auto CC is there)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qwAVlfm0tjk&pp=ygUbbmlrYWgga2kgc2FoaSB1bWFyIEJyIEltcmFu

Reaching puberty and manifesting its physical signs is what makes one a baligh in Islamic law - see At what age does a person become an adult in Islam?
So, for example, if a child commits a crime then the Hadd or Qisas will only be enforced on him if he has reached puberty, regardless of whether he has received sex education.
However there are some specific matters in which the ruling might change before having reached puberty. For example:

أو الطفل الذين لم يظهروا على عورات النساء
children who are not yet aware of the private aspects of women
— Quran 24:31

Hijab is waived in front of children, but according to some scholars it is still required in part or in full in front of children who are aware of the private aspects of women or can feel sexual desire or are expected to describe what they see to others.

جَزَاكَ ٱللَّٰهُ خَيْرًا
